# How to create Dockerfile which installs Python 3 and nltk in a Ubuntu container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, nltk, dockerfile

I am trying to create a Docker container with python 3 and nltk tokenizer. Can anyone help me with creation on of Dockerfile.

Comment: Post your dockerfile that you are trying

Comment: anaconda environments are more stable than docker. And also you need to do some sort of volume mounting for `nltk_data`. Docker containers are not that optimal to use NLTK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `Dockerfile` which installs `nltk` via the `python3-nltk` debian package (and demonstrates that it indeed works)

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python3-nltk && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
CMD ["python3", "-c", "import nltk"]
```

Note that the `apt-get` boilerplate is suggested in [the dockerfile best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it out,.

Answer (score 0):

You can begin your Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:3-wheezy

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git ca-certificates

RUN pip install -q nltk

#optionally your other docker commands here
```

Then build and run the container.

Obs: This is a official debian based container (compatible with ubuntu) if you like a pure ubuntu container replace "python:3-wheezy" with "dominga/uwsgi-python3" which is built from ubuntu14

Comment: Title says "ubuntu" and this dockerfile is debian